# Porqué al tratar de modificar un archivo en C++ .. no me agrega lo que le pido que me agregue?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en donde debo "hacer" una tintorería, me pide consultar catálogo, agregar subservicio, eliminar subservicio y hacer notas. Pero al tratar de agregar un subservicio, donde quiero agregar texto (en el string) no se refleja en el archivo. Me gustaría saber si estoy haciendo algo mal o si me salté algo.

```
void modtint() {
    ofstream archivo;
    string textito;
    char n[3];
    char c[10];
    archivo.open("contin.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Digite el numero de subservicio: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Proporcione el nombre de su subservicio: ";
    cin >> textito;
    getline(cin,textito);
    archivo << endl << n << "   |   "<< textito << "        |   ";
    cout << "Digite el costo de su subservicio: ";
    cin >> c;
    archivo << c << "   |";
    archivo.close();
    system("cls");
    main();
}
```

Más que nada sería en la variable textito, cuando utilizo el getline, no me lo muestra en la pantalla.

```
    string textito;

    char n[3];
    char c[10];
```

Estos dos últimos si me los muestra.. al asignarle valores pero el string no me lo toma, los deja en blanco.
Intenté mover de posición el getline, el cin de mi variable, moví casi todo y no cambia en nada.

Comment: ¿Has probado borrando el `cin >> textito;` de antes del `getline(cin,textito)`. Por cierto **NO DEBES** llamar a `main` desde otra función.

Comment: Okay... Ya quité el [cin >> textito] , y ahora no me deja agregar texto a esa variable....  y me gustaria saber porqué no debo llamar al [main] desde otra función??.. soy nuevo en esto de la programación y quiero saber!

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con "*no me deja agregar texto a esa variable*". El por qué no se debe llamar `main` desde otra función es una cuestión suficientemente compleja como para merecer que redactes una pregunta completa.